# How to get the value of column that the same for few rows by selecting values from other columns?

Tags: mysql, select

Since I am not a MySQL expert, I am having trouble determining how to ask a search engine for advice on this topic.

I have the following table:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
| product_id | attribute_id | text              |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|       1770 |           57 | wi-fi             |
|       1770 |           58 | bluetooth         |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

There are many other products with many attributes.

I need to select `product_id` that has `text` = `wi-fi` and `text` = `bluetooth` (in different rows). The table name is `product_attribute`.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_attribute 
WHERE product_attribute.text = 'wi-fi' 
    AND product_attribute.text = 'bluetooth';
```

However no results are returned since in one row we have `text = wi-fi` and another row has `text = bluetooth`, whereas my query is looking for both `wi-fi` and `bluetooth` in the same row.

How can I get `product_id = 1770` by making the query select from the `text` column in different rows with the same `product_id`?

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96a938/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is close but doesn't work because no row will satisfy both `text='wi-fi' AND text='bluetooth'` at the same time.

You could use a self join instead:

```
SELECT
  pa1.*
FROM
  product_attribute pa1
  JOIN
  product_attribute pa2
  ON pa1.product_id = pa2.product_id
WHERE
  pa1.text = 'wi-fi'
  AND
  pa2.text = 'bluetooth'
;
```

That way the first version of the table (`pa1`) matches `text='wi-fi'`, the second version(`pa2`) matches `text='bluetooth'`, and the `JOIN` condition (`pa1.product_id = pa2.product_id`) ensures both conditions are met for a single product.

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
SELECT product_attribute.product_id
FROM product_attribute 
WHERE product_attribute.text = 'wi-fi' 
    OR product_attribute.text = 'bluetooth'
GROUP BY product_attribute.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

The idea here is to use an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause to allow rows that have either `wi-fi` or `bluetooth` in the `text` column, then we only return products that have at least two rows.

Thanks to [@jkavalik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64556/jkavalik) for creating a test [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96a938/5) that works, and proves the above code!